# Passing Input to ajax returns empty data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to pass user input to ajax like this:

```
var input = JSON.stringify({
  name: $("#event-title").val(),
  date: $("#event-date").val(),
  start: $("#event-st").val(),
  end: $("#event-et").val()
});

var requests = {
  set: createRequest("POST", "add", input),
  get: createRequest("GET", "events")
};

function createRequest(type, method, data) {
  return {
    type: type,
    url:
      "https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/" + method,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: update,
    error: logError
  };
}
```

When I press the submit button I call an ajax request like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#event-form").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax(requests.set); // Ajax call
      $(".modal").removeClass("is-active");
    });
  });
```

But the problem is that when I check my Cloudwatch logs I get an empty data that looks like this: `{ name: '', date: '', start: '', end: '' }`

Comment: Is your input field's names correct?

Comment: From what you've shown it looks like the values of input are set when the page loads. If you're expecting the user entered values to be fetched it's not going to work.

Comment: my input data is correct how can I pass the data into a function in an object

Comment: Have you tried passing the data (`input`) without stringify-ing it?

Comment: I get a 502 error when i send non strinified json

Comment: Move your `var input = ...` and `var requests = ...` parts inside the submit event handler. Your issue is exactly as @H77 points out; you're trying to get the input values **before** they even have values

Comment: Thanks, adding 'requests.set.data = input;' in the submit handler worked.